# How AccountManager knows what Google account to use?

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I am trying to implement [Google rest api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#errors_and_suggested_actions) for Drive V3 in Android.

But I am getting **authError**

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"authError",
            "message":"Invalid Credentials",
            "locationType":"header",
            "location":"Authorization"
         }
      ],
      "code":401,
      "message":"Invalid Credentials"
   }
}
```

I use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to get token from user, and I think it access the wrong console account.
How does it know what account to access?

This is my AccountManager code, I successfully get user token. Also I invalidate it before with `AccountManager.invalidateAuthToken`

```
    Bundle options = new Bundle();
    options.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
    accountManager.getAuthToken(account, scope, options, context,
            callback, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) docs for [getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken(android.accounts.Account, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle, android.app.Activity, android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback, android.os.Handler)):

> Gets an auth token of the specified type for a particular account, **prompting the user for credentials if necessary**. This method is intended for applications running in the foreground where it makes sense to ask the user directly for a password.
>
> **If a previously generated auth token is cached for this account and type, then it is returned**. Otherwise, **if a saved password is available, it is sent to the server to generate a new auth token. Otherwise, the user is prompted to enter a password.**

It seems that it may depend on the value of your `account` variable that you are passing in the `getAuthToken()`.

You probably already have this in, but gonna included in for the community, did you include the `USE_CREDENTIALS` permission as mentioned in the docs:

> **NOTE**: If targeting your app to work on API level 22 and before, **USE_CREDENTIALS** permission is needed for those platforms.

Hope this helps. Good luck. :)

Comment: We are talking about Google account here. It should obviously be the same for all the projects. It is the project number I am after, I don't think I been logged in to the right one.

Comment: Sorry. I got confused. In your post you were asking on how the `AccountManager` which account to access, to which I provided what I thought was the appropriate answer. Can you elaborate more? Are you testing the Drive API using a device that is in sync with multiple Google accounts?